# Сортировка отображение закладок в firefox

Tags: firefox

Как сделать так чтобы добавляемые закладки в папку закладок браузера, были сверху, а не "падали" вниз?

При создании (переносе вкладки в папку закладки строки закладок браузера) закладки, она "падает" вниз.

Нужны скриншоты, чтобы было понятней.

[image: 1]

В папке закладок 1 закладка

[image: 2]

После добавления еще одной (эта страница), закладка оказывается внизу списка. А я хочу чтобы она была сверху.

Я давно-давно сделал чтобы в "последних добавленных закладках" было не 10 или 20 закладок, а 50. Возможно есть решение и этой "проблемы" с сортировкой/отображением?

Может такой вопрос тут не нужно было задавать? К программированию он не имеет прямого отношения.

Answer (score 1):

Эта проблема решается расширениями с функцией сортировки закладок. Например, 
[Auto-Sort Bookmarks](https://addons.mozilla.org/ru/firefox/addon/auto-sort-bookmarks/). Это расширение может сортировать закладки в том числе при создании новой.

Comment: нужно попробовать. А без дополнений никак нельзя?

Comment: Наверное можно соорудить что-то в консоли, но подумайте так - всё равно ж сортировку придётся каждый раз запускать вручную! Варианты типа пересборки FF со своими настройками даже не предлагаю.

Comment: расширение запускать вручную? думаю там есть какая-то кнопка

Comment: Расширение запускать не нужно. Оно само все умеет делать. А вот если без дополнений и расширений, тот тут совсем без ручной работы не обойтись.

Comment: не знаю. еще не ставил это расширение.

Comment: глянул я на это расширение. немножко не оно. Оно сортирует ВСЕ закладки в меню закладок, на панели закладок, и еще что-то. Не зн., может еще раз, внимательнее, нужно глянуть...